# Changing wallpaper via cron - difficulty with gnome-session PID

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables

I'm trying to change the desktop wallpaper via cron/bash. I've read a lot of questions and answers on this site an apparently I have to do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_FILE_PATH=/home/$USER/file.jpg

PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

sleep 5

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://$MY_FILE_PATH
```

But if run `./my_script.sh` I get

```
grep: /proc/X1: Is a directory
grep: X2/environ: No such file or directory
```

`X1` and `X2` are two different numbers and of course cron doesn't work

**EDIT**

If I manually set PID to one of the two numbers I get (on the line where export is made)

for X1 (829):

```
permission denied
```

for X2 (1394):

```
warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `pgrep -a gnome-session` - it sounds like you have 2 `gnome-session` processes running (which will make it tricky to figure out which one to apply the setting to)

Comment: The output is 829 1394. Right now I'm on windows running a virtual machine to test this. Could that be it?

Comment: I was hoping the `-a` would give additional information about the origin of the processes

Comment: @steeldriver I'm sorry. I've missed the -a I will get back at you. In the meantime see my edit

Comment: @steeldriver requested ouput: `829 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gm/greeter/autostart 1394 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu`

Comment: I assume you mistyped that (`gm` should be `gdm`)? if so, since the greeter likely runs as root, you could qualify the match using the current user `PID=(pgrep -u $USER gnome-session)`. Be aware that `$USER` might not be set by default in crontabs - I assume you have addressed that already since you use it elsewhere in your script.

Comment: both `pgreg -u $USER` and `$USER` not avalilable in cron was what made it work! Post it like an answer if you like!! Thank you very much